# How to find specific row in Python CSV module

Tags: python, csv

I need to find the third row from column 4 to the end of the a CSV file. How would I do that? I know I can find the values from the 4th column on with 
    row[3]
but how do I get specifically the third row?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could convert the csv reader object into a list of lists... The rows are stored in a list, which contains lists of the columns.

So:

```
csvr = csv.reader(file)
csvr = list(csvr)
csvr[2]     # The 3rd row
csvr[2][3]  # The 4th column on the 3rd row.
csvr[-4][-3]# The 3rd column from the right on the 4th row from the end
```

Answer (score 1):

You could keep a counter for counting the number of rows:

```
counter = 1
for row in reader:
    if counter == 3:
        print('Interested in third row')
    counter += 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `itertools.islice` to extract the row of data you wanted, then index into it.

Note that the rows and columns are numbered from zero, not one.

```
import csv
from itertools import islice

def get_row_col(csv_filename, row, col):
    with open(csv_filename, 'rb') as f:
        return next(islice(csv.reader(f), row, row+1))[col]
```

Answer (score 0):

This one is a very basic code that will do the job and you can easily make a function out of it.

```
import csv

target_row = 3
target_col = 4

with open('yourfile.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    n = 0
    for row in reader:
        if row == target_row:
            data = row.split()[target_col]
            break

print data
```